# Page looks differently between html file and html inside php file

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I've created a simple html and it looks perfectly
But when I use it as maintenance for my wordpress site it has lesser height that expected. CSS and inner HTML are completely the same, I've just inserted html inside maintenance.php
There are some screens to show what I mean:

[image: Just HTML]
[image: HTML inside php]

The problems seems to be that  height is not full screen, but I can't tell the difference

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please, visit [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please, provide more info on efforts you made and share some code.

Comment: You may find it helpful to see what html differences there are (compare the source of both versions) and  use something like firefox's 'inspect element' to see what css is being applied.  If there is ANY difference in the source, that may explain why some css is being applied in one and not the other.